# MVP - What adjustment must be made to enable a "UiField FlowPanel" to work (rather than "UiField SimplePanel"?

Tags: gwt, mvp, uibinder

I changed my "topPanel" UiField to refer to a FlowPanel rather than a SimplePanel.
--But, when I do this, the original "setWidget" method in my "View" class is no longer valid.

What adjustment (--if any can be made) can I make to allow the FlowPanel "@UiField" to be compile and process correctly?

Here is the "View" Class...

```
    public class TopPanel extends Composite implements AcceptsOneWidget 
    {
    -
    -
    -
    //...prev...@UiField
    //...prev...SimplePanel topPanel;

    //...Trying to make this work...
    @UiField
    FlowPanel topPanel;    
    -
    -
    -
    //...how should this method be modified or replaced to allow the FlowPanel "@UiField" to work?....
    @Override
    public void setWidget(IsWidget w)
    {
        topPanel.setWidget(w);
    }    
}
```

Here is the uiBinder template...

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style src="app.css" />
    <g:HTMLPanel width="50%" height="50%">
        <!--  <g:SimplePanel ui:field="topPanel"> -->   
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="topPanel">
            <g:Button text="from aaa: go to bbb" ui:field="topButtonA"></g:Button>
            <g:Button text="from bbb: go to ccc" ui:field="topButtonB"></g:Button>
            <g:Button text="from ccc: go to aaa" ui:field="topButtonC"></g:Button>
        </g:FlowPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: What is the exact exception or error you are seeing?

Comment: "The method setWidget(IsWidget) is undefined for the type FlowPanel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
topPanel.insert(w,0)
```

instead of

```
topPanel.setWidget(w)
```

Comment: Actually, the "view" class is called "TopPanel".  The "TopPanel.ui.xml" contains a tag called "topPanel" (confusing, I guess), which corresponds to a "@UiField topPanel" in the "TopPanel" view class.

Comment: [continued] ...The "TopPanel" view class is defined as "public class TopPanel extends Composite implements AcceptsOneWidget"... One of the implemented methods that is required for this definition is "setWidget".   When I changed the "@UiField" from a "SimplePanel" to a "FlowPanel", the IDE (or compiler) disallowed the "topPanel.setWidget(w)"...  I'll try the "topPanel.insert" and let you know what happens... --Thanks for your help

Comment: topPanel is the name of the FlowPanel as indicated by @UiField and ui:field in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the widget below/after the buttons contained in the topPanel, you should use:

```
topPanel.add(w)
```